# Grayscale in matlab

Tags: matlab, grayscale

I'm trying to convert a 2D array to grayscale but using mat2gray doesn't do anything and imshow() appears to create a binary image that when I graph I cannot rotate it, e.g. the original array is 2d but maps in 3d. So, what is the best way to take a grayscale of 2d array in Matlab so if you have A=rand(5,10) or something and want to take a grayscale of that, what is the best way?

Comment: What is the range of the values in the original 2D array? Could you say more about what you mean by 'cannot rotate it'?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect [MAT2GRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/mat2gray.html) to work, but if it doesn't you can try this:

```
A = rand(5,10);     %# Make a random array of values between 0 and 1
B = uint8(255.*A);  %# Scale the values and convert them to uint8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `imshow` on a 2D image, it is a good idea to use autoscaling.

```
img = randn(100);
imshow(img,[]);
```