# Grayscale of an image

Tags: matlab

I have a picture which 960*1280 unit8 in gray color, so how can I convert it to 256 level of gray scale at matlab?

I could get the picture that has 256 level with "imshow(img, [0 255])" , but I want to get it to a variable something like img256.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954600/grayscale-in-matlab?rq=1

Comment: Shouldn't a `uint8 in gray color` already have a range of `0:255`? Or is this actually `960*1280*3 uint8 rgb`?

Answer (score 1):

Does `rgb2gray` from Image Processing Toolbox do what you need?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
img256 = imadjust(img,[],[0; 255]);
```

or:

```
img256=img/(max(img(:))-min(img(:)))*255;
```